# Utilizar componente jquery dentro de um formData (fileupload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Amigos, estou utilizando o plugin de fileupload do jquery e utilizando a seguinte callback:

```
jQuery("#fileupload").fileupload({
    url: '/painel/uploads',
    dataType: 'json',
    formData: {_token: jQuery("#fileupload").data('token'), idpasta: jQuery("#list-id-client").html()},
    done: function (e, data) {

    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
});
```

Estou imprimindo esta request com o comando dd() do PHP e percebi que quando imprimo "idpasta" tenho o seguinte cenário: algumas vezes vem o ID corretamente e outras não vem nada, apenas uma string vazia.

Acredito que seja uma requisição assíncrona e eu esteja pegando dados de outro componente do jQuery e isso esteja me dando problemas.

Se eu imprimir por console.log(jQuery("#list-id-client").html()) sempre retorna algo, diferente da requisição ajax.

Existe algo que possa ser feito? Preciso pegar esse ID do cliente por jQuery...

Obrigado

Comment: Adicione o parametro: 'async:false' na requisição, e veja se permanece o problema.

Comment: Se eu colocar async:false, o plugin deixa de funcionar. =( Tem alguma outra ideia?

Comment: O elemento "#list-id-client" é um input ?

Comment: Na verdade é um span que contém o número que eu preciso. Esse span é preenchido com o número que eu preciso antes de chamar esse método que estou usando. Se eu adicionar um beforeSend: {console.log("#list-id-client")} eu consigo ver claramente que o que eu preciso está lá, porém não estou conseguindo manipular o beforeSend pra que eu consiga garantir que esse dado vá para a rota que eu desejo.

Comment: Saquei, você submete esse formulário como ? tem algum evento jQuery em algum botão ou você fez ele identificar direto no submit ? acho que o erro é a  sincronia mesmo

Comment: Realmente o erro foi de sincronia. Olhei na documentação do próprio plugin, existe um método chamado .bind que resolveu o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo!

Comment: Nice, responda sua própria pergunta com a solução, pode ajudar mais pessoas!

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta, era erro de sincronismo mesmo.

O próprio plugin disponibiliza um método bind. Olhei na documentação e consegui implementar o seguinte, que resolveu o problema:

```
jQuery("#fileupload")
    .bind('fileuploadsubmit', function(e, data) {
        var idPasta = $("#idPasta").val();
        data.formData = {_token: jQuery("#fileupload").data('token'), idpasta: idPasta};
    })

    .fileupload({
    url: '/painel/uploads',
    dataType: 'json',

    done: function (e, data) {

    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }
});
```

Agradecido!